# could not load assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#-4.0

I am working on a windows application and I am using another dll with name diffplex. I have stored it in the bin folder of my solution. in properties I have set it as copy local = false.

When I am running the program from visual studio it is working fine. But when I copy exe from bin to some other location and try to use this application I am getting this error - "could not load assembly or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified"

Please find the screen shot attached. But I want to give my client only exe file not the dll file. What can I do.[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to include the dll file with the distribution

Comment: If your program needs this dll how can you run it without it?

Comment: If you want to give something easy to use for client, consider using an installer since your program will need the DLL.

Comment: Is there no way to include it in exe

Comment: Hi Finally the issue has been fixed. A tool MS ILmerge is used which on post build event makes both exe and dll as one file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Finally the issue has been fixed. A tool MS ILmerge is used which on post build event makes both exe and dll as one file